# How to handle network calls in Microservices architecture

Tags: networking, architecture, rx-java, haproxy, microservices

We are using Micro services architecture where top services are used for exposing REST API's to end user and backend services does the work of querying database.

When we get **1 user request we make ~30k requests to backend service**. We are using RxJava for top service so all 30K requests gets executed in parallel.
We are using haproxy to distribute the load between backend services.
However when we get 3-5 user requests we are getting network connection Exceptions, No Route to Host Exception, Socket connection Exception.

What are the best practices for this kind of use case?

Comment: I have little experience in this, but 30k request to the backend sound too much.

Comment: Seems like you are hit by the fallacies of distributed computing: The network is reliable, Latency is Zero, Bandwidth is infinite, etc.
Reading this sounds more like a layered architecture where it takes multiple layers to get to the data.

Comment: 30k requests means at least 30,000 bits of information being requested from the back end (response orientated data) or being pushed into the back end (logging data).  What sort of a website are you providing which requires that amount of data movement for a single user request?  It sounds like the architecture and approach is broken and needs to be revisited imho...

Answer (score 19):

Well you ended up with the classical microservice mayhem. It's completely irrelevant what technologies you employ - the problem lays within the way you applied the concept of microservices!

It is natural in this architecture, that services call each other (preferably that should happen asynchronously!!). Since I know only little about your service APIs I'll have to make some assumptions about what went wrong in your backend:

I assume that a user makes a request to one service. This service will now (obviously synchronously) query another service and receive these 30k records you described. Since you probably have to know more about these records you now have to make another request per record to a third service/endpoint to aggregate all the information your frontend requires!

This shows me that you probably got the whole thing with [bounded contexts](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) wrong! So much for the analytical part. Now to the solution:

Your API should return all the information along with the query that enumerates them! Sometimes that could seem like a contradiction to the kind of isolation and authority over data/state that the microservices pattern specifies - but it is not feasible to isolate data/state in one service only because that leads to the problem you currently have - all other services HAVE to query that data every time to be able to return correct data to the frontend! However it is possible to duplicate it as long as the authority over the data/state is clear!

Let me illustrate that with an example: Let's assume you have a classical shop system. Articles are grouped. Now you would probably write two microservices - one that handles articles and one that handles groups! And you would be right to do so! You might have already decided that the group-service will hold the relation to the articles assigned to a group! Now if the frontend wants to show all items in a group - what happens: The group service receives the request and returns 30'000 Article numbers in a beautiful JSON array that the frontend receives. This is where it all goes south: The frontend now has to query the article-service for every article it received from the group-service!!! Aaand your're screwed!

Now there are multiple ways to solve this problem: One is (as previously mentioned) to duplicate article information to the group-service: So every time an article is assigned to a group using the group-service, it has to read all the information for that article form the article-service and store it to be able to return it with the *get-me-all-the-articles-in-group-x* query. This is fairly simple but keep in mind that you will need to update this information when it changes in the article-service or you'll be serving stale data from the group-service. Event-Sourcing can be a very powerful tool in this use case and [I suggest you read up on it](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)! You can also use simple messages sent from one service (in this case the article-service) to a message bus of your preference and make the group-service listen and react to these messages.

Another very simple quick-and-dirty solution to your problem could also be just to provide a new REST endpoint on the articles services that takes an array of article-ids and returns the information to all of them which would be much quicker. This could probably solve your problem very quickly.

A good rule of thumb in a backend with microservices is to aspire for a constant number of these cross-service calls which means your number of calls that go across service boundaries should never be directly related to the amount of data that was requested! We closely monitory what service calls are made because of a given request that comes through our API to keep track of what services calls what other services and where our performance bottlenecks will arise or have been caused. Whenever we detect that a service makes many (there is no fixed threshold but everytime I see >4 I start asking questions!) calls to other services we investigate why and how this could be fixed! There are some great metrics tools out there that can help you with tracing requests across service boundaries!

Let me know if this was helpful or not, and whatever solution you implemented!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.
The assumption you made perfectly describes what we are trying to do, i would like to add few more details here group service uses Elastic Search (query flexibility) and Article service uses Cassandra for storage(large volume data). 
Creating one more REST endpoint in article service to accept list of id's sounds feasible, this way we will be reducing the no of article service call.
However URLs have a size limitation and we cant pass all 30K ids to one article service call. 
Please share your views on this.

Comment: Oh, then use the HTTP body of the request! The URI is the wrong place to send this kind of data! 

Comment: Yes we can do that, but that way we wont be able to achieve the parallelism we want
i.e. when we get 1 group request only one article service will be active while other instances of article service doing nothing.
Instead of sending all ids to article service in one call, we can send fixed no of id's in multiple article service call.
However this violates the rule of thumb you mentioned in answer.

Comment: True, but lets take a step back: querying 30'000 records from a DB takes as little as < 50ms if indexed correctly, plus some network overhead - I hope you have more serous problems than this! If you need it faster I recommend you look into some other industry leading tools like MemCached or something like this! Sending the 30k records over a single HTTP request is much more efficient than paying the request/response/networklatency cost for 300 (100 records / request) http requests. Another plus is that the response could be cached! My recommendation: Keep it simple - scale it when you need it!

Comment: yes, that's true for typical REST application, but in our case one request steam ~2 million records for 1 min time window and session last at-least for 180 second, so i believe its lot of overhead on only one article service.
also caching so much data is not feasible.
Can we implement Micro services architecture without sacrificing the parallelism and performance with minimal network calls.

Comment: Well there is a good reason, that typical REST applications don't do that; It's bad practise/archtecture! If a response keeps a resource busy for 180 sec. per request, this resource can only process a very small number or requests (4-36 depending on your processors Architecture) so overloading your system is very much a guarantee! Usually these kinds of usecases call for paging the result sets! Like that you could also do loadbalancing again!!

Comment: All this goes way off the original topic of your question. What I'd like to suggest to you is, that you keep reading up on microservices architectural style, all the goodies and badies, that come with it and the new challenges you will face. I get the feeling you're currently in over your head and need some more time to sketch out your architecture and ask some important questions like what kinds of loads will you get and how can you make them actually manageble, what kinds of balancing methods to use, what bounded contexts to draw etc. The list goes on and on!

Comment: Microservices are a wonderfull kind of architecture but come at a severe price in development scaling, orchestration and operational complexity. It's not for faint-hearted; are you absolutely sure, it's the way to go for you and your product?!?